# Installing package via Ubuntu Software

Tags: ubuntu

I have recently installed Ubuntu and am a bit of a noob, so forgive me for anything stupid I say.

I'm trying to install Chrome, and having downloaded via Firefox I am now trying to install it via the Ubuntu Software tool, but when clicking the Install button nothing happens:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this a sudo access thing, e.g. install as admin if I was on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: it will be installed go to ubuntu dashbord (where you search for apps ) the icon on top left corner  and type chrome you will be able to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this in a terminal window.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Cool thanks, so why would this not work in the GUI, is this a limitation with certain third party providers, should I always just use terminal commands when installing packages? I'm a noob with Linux but dont mind using terminal if thats the best way to learn

Comment: to be honest, once you get the hang of command line, nothing else touches it.  You need to remember that a GUI is just an interface between the user and the CLI anyway.   As for your issue, I can only assume that the installer for the particular package youve selected isnt working.  But because its GUI, its likely you cant see the error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you got that result.Normally,when you click install ,it will pop up a window asking for authorization.Maybe you should reboot and try it again.